# How to search a list of URIs matching a pattern in marklogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I'm new to XML database so i need some help with marklogic and xquery.

I did record some documents in a database and when i push explore button their URIs show up and looks like (for instance) :

`/firstDirectory/documentA.xml`

`/firstDirectory/documentB.xml`

`/secondDirectory/documentC.xml`

Now i want to get the list of URIs of all documents which are located in 'firstDirectory'.
So i need something like that :

`List<URI> unknownXQueryFunction("/firstDirectory/");`

Sadly, i'm unable to find the function i need while watching into MarkLogic API. I tried some stuff with collection / document / document-uri / base-uri / directory but none did the trick :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

This applies a directory query to cts:uris, which should be a more accurate approach than cts:uri-match, depending on how your directories are organized:

```
cts:uris((),'document' cts:directory-query('/firstDirectory/','infinity'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [cts:uris](http://developer.marklogic.com/pubs/5.0/apidocs/Lexicons.html#cts%3auris)("/firstDirectory/", "document") if you have enabled uri lexicon.

Comment: Thanks for the clue Andrew : cts:uri-match("/firstDirectory/*") made it. I just need to sort nodes and leafs but i got data that i need :)